# The graphical interface of Android applications looks different on the mobile screen compared to the project

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

This is the graphical interface inside Android Studio:

[image]

But when you're going to run the same app on your mobile screen, see how some components don't line up as they were lined up in the Android Studio project:

[image]

Please how to fix?
This happens in many Android Studio projects.

You can see that the constraints are correct:

[image]

Comment: Posting layout XML would come a long way in matter of finding the issue. What I think you have is left button is set to be at the middle between last text and bottom while right one has arbitrary constraint like 80% between top and bottom so it won't stay aligned when screen configuration changes even slightly.

Answer (score 1):

As it's shown with your screenshot, you have put constraints on your image, but no constraints indicate that your images need to be horizontally aligned.

I see two options:

1. Put your two images in a LineraLayout (horizontal)

   - Add constraints on this layout
2. Add constraints on your image to be horizontally centered.

   - Image1 top to Image2 top
   - Image1 Bottom to Image2 bottom
   - Image1 end to Image2 start

[image: Something like that]

Comment: Hello MG1616. Thank you very much for your answer. As you wrote, am uploading two images showing what happens according to what you wrote. Please, pay attention on the differences:
In the Android Studio project:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/r-rQsY0

What is the shown on the phone screen:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/YH-zMks

Comment: The preview on Android Studio project will not be the same as on the real phone screen. Especially when the top and bottom constraint are not properly set. Could you edit your question and post the layout XML ?